# Проблема с: Horizon View Standard 6 и AutoDesk 3dMAX

Tags: view

Приветствую.

Натолкнулись на проблему c AutoDesk 3dMAX.

На компьютере:
 i5/4G/integrVGA/SSD
изменение масштаба, перемещение объектов происходит в реальном времени.

На виртуальной машине, в пуле:

4 CPU\16G\3dHardware(512M)
 с замиранием на 2-3 секунды и рывками.

Как быть, кто-нибудь сталкивался?
Спасибо.

Конфигурация:
Кластер:
Сервера DELL R720 (2xIntel Xeon E5-2680v2 2.8GHz, 128G, AMD FirePro S9000 (share), Intel X520 DP 10Gb DA / SFP) x3
СХД EMC VNXe 20T
Сеть кластер Сisco 4500x 16x10G x2

Установлено:
ESXi 5.5
VMWare Horizon View Standard 6

Денис.